# google developers console Project ID is not available - but must use this Project ID

Tags: console, project

oneall.com social login gives me Project name and Project ID, I cannot choose a name. I create a New Project 3 weeks ago but requested it removed because of an error which took about 2 weeks for google to clear it out. I go in now to create a new project using the Project name and Project ID oneall.com gives me but google gives me an error "Project ID is not available".

Is there any solution?

thank you,

TBP