# Google Cloud: The Project ID specified is not available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Basically the same as the following two,

- [google developers console Project ID is not available - but must use this Project ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483624/google-developers-console-project-id-is-not-available-but-must-use-this-projec), which the OP says (in 2014) it took ***more than 2 weeks*** but still not available.
- [Google Developers Console : "The Project ID specified is not available. Please select another. These identifiers must be unique."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695340/google-developers-console-the-project-id-specified-is-not-available-please-s), which the OP says (in 2015) *"Logged in **the next day** and the Project ID was available without having to do anything"*.

however, it's 2022 and I deleted a project with Google Cloud cli several days ago, and tried to create another one with the same name/id now, but it is still not available/working.

How long do I have to wait, and where / how can I check such Google Cloud *"internal cache records"*?

Comment: The answer would seem to be "at least 30 days"; https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6251787?hl=en#zippy=%2Cshut-down-a-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete a project, you can recover that project within 30 days (undelete). That means the Project ID is not available until the project has been permanently deleted.

Comment: Actually you can never use again any Project ID,  even if you delete the project and wait 30 days.